# Cordova localStorage phone backup

Tags: cordova, local-storage

Does the Cordova localStorage get backed up with a local iTunes phone backup?

Meaning, if I restore a phone from backup in iTunes, will the localStorage be restored as well for the app?

Reason I ask is for when I register push notifications in the app, I'd like to present a dialog, and save in localStorage that I did show this dialog, which explains what types of push notifications a user could expect from my app, instead of blindly registering the app with push.  This way the user could see some benefits of keeping push enabled on the device or choose not to have push notifications.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it will.

Lets try a simple App first and save some values in localstorage and then sync with iTunes and then re-store.

Normally when using `localstorage` it saves data in `NSLibraryDirectory or NSDocumentDirectory` which should be available after restore or upgrade.

Plus as described below that **iTunes** does restore **Web App cache/databases** i.e. local storage.

**What iTunes backs up**

- **Autofill** for webpages.
- **Offline web app cache/database.**

**Full listing**: http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4946

Comment: Sounds good, so I shouldn't rely on localStorage to keep information regarding push dialogs or whatnot, because that information will persist even after a backup restore to a device.  When restoring a backup onto a device in iTunes, and you open an app you have to re-authorize that app for push notifications, so storing the information that I've already registered push through that way is not correct.  There must be a way I can query the push registration to determine if the app has attempted registering push.  I am using a library for push registration, I may need to expand on it.  Thank you.

Comment: What i understood; one suggestion. In case if you have something on server-side then you can store a specific token/value on both sides i.e. on server and in the app as well. Based on the token you can verify which app and user has subscribed for push and what push message he is interesting in to receive. So whenever user opt-in push subscription, you simply re-generate a fresh token with relevant info and save on both sides. hope it will give you some idea or help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It **depends**.

In general iOS won't backup caches.

```
However, iCloud and iTunes do not back up the contents of the following directories:

<Application_Home>/AppName.app
<Application_Data>/Library/Caches
<Application_Data>/tmp
```

[From Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17)

But since Cordova 3.0. Cordova has had the key `BackupWebStorage`.

> Set to `cloud` to allow web storage data to backup via iCloud. Set to
>   `local` to allow only local backups via iTunes sync. Set to `none` prevent
>   web storage backups.

[From Cordova 4.0 iOS Configuration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html)